# Make it possible for users to download packages to source folder and build them there

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

How can I gives users (Í'm the admin) permissions to download packages to `/usr/local/src` and build them there?

Comment: Is your question limited to building software in `/usr/local/src`, or do you want users to be able to install them in `/usr/local`?

Comment: I want to make it possible for users to to download software packages to /usr/local/src and build them there, so I need to give them write permissions, but how do I do that?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Debian and its derivatives (including Ubuntu as far as I know) have a `src` group which is intended for this, albeit historically in `/usr/src` (which used to be owned by the `src` group by default, and group writable — that's [no longer the case for systems installed after 2010 though](https://bugs.debian.org/573701)).

To adapt this to `/usr/local/src`, you just need to set that directory up appropriately:

```
chown root:src /usr/local/src
chmod 775 /usr/local/src
```

then add the appropriate users to the `src` group:

```
adduser user1 src
```

You can apply the same technique using any group of your choosing. For example with a new group called `localsrc`:

```
addgroup localsrc
chown root:localsrc /usr/local/src
chmod 775 /usr/local/src
adduser user1 localsrc
```

Additionally, if you want the directories created by your users to be themselves writable by anyone in the group, you should add the group sticky bit:

```
chmod 2775 /usr/local/src
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04. I do have the `src` group. i.e. `% grep src /etc/group` returns `src:x:40:`. But `/usr/src` is still owned by root. `% ls -adl /usr/src/` gives `drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Aug 30 11:13 /usr/src/`

Comment: @the_velour_fog thanks, just goes to show how long ago I installed my main system! `/usr/src`'s default ownership was changed in 2010 (to fix [#573701](https://bugs.debian.org/573701). I'll update my answer...

Comment: I tried this out and its working well for me, its nice to not have to take those extra permission steps everytime I work with source. On my personal system (laptop) I don't need to bother about other users on my machine so - knowing I don't really have mulit-user permission issues - could I have simply given myself  direct ownership of `/usr/local/src` ? and maybe left root as the group? i.e. `ls -ald /usr/local/src` would give:     `drwxrwxr-x  3 velour root     4096 Sep 14 21:27 /usr/local/src` I know its  a bit nit picky, I just wondered if it would be feasible.

Comment: @the_velour_fog it would be feasible, and allowable — you're free to do whatever you like under `/usr/local`.